# How to handle syncs between server instances in a cloud?

Tags: php, cloud

i'm wondering how the sync of cloud instances is done. There're a lot of PHP cloud providers, who always say you can simply set up a lamp stack and fill your db and upload your php files and simply open another instance of THAT server (which looks like a 1:1 copy to me) to handle peak load times etc. But, how do they sync ? I mean, is there a realtime-DB-sync ? And a real-time-filesystem-sync ? What's about PHP SESSIONs if you session is stored on server A but next pageview sends you to server B ?

Or am I missing something here ?

Comment: sorry, but I totally disagree to the mod's closing of this question ! this thing is highly important for a lot of everyday php question, like uploads, logs, sessions and everything that's a little bit filesystem-related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all honesty it depends on the host and the host's cloud platform.

In the case of PHP sessions, it's based off of the domain.  Sessions can carry over to anything with *.domain.com.

Most hosts use a software load balancer to accomplish this.  The software will clone the vm, add the new vm to a software load balancer, and edit the configurations necessary to make it auto scale.

As far as mysql scaling, again depending on the host, it may be a shared database.  Multiple VMs can connect to one shared database and push/pull data.

A lot of how the system works is based on the host.  Each host is different.  Some use OpenStack, which can be autoscaled. Some use OnApp which autoscales.  Some use cloudstack, which somewhat autoscales.  Some hosts have built their own auto scale platform.  It all depends ;).  I'd love to explain more but there are plenty of resources online based on each host that tell how they do it!

For more info how onApp does it, check out http://loadbalancer.org/virtual_appliance.php They use this software modified to work with multiple hypervisors.